# Error in ionic project creation

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Creating directory `.\testapp2` - done!

√ Downloading and extracting blank starter - done!

? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes

√ Personalizing `ionic.config.json` and `package.json` - done!

> `ionic integrations enable cordova --quiet`

√ Downloading integration cordova - done!

√ Copying integrations files to project - done!

[OK] Added cordova integration!

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

- IONIC  DEVAPP  *

  Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app
- Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
- LiveReload for instant style and JS updates

  ️-->    Install DevApp:  <--

> npm i
>   × Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1):

```
    > node-sass@4.7.2 install C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/install.js

    Skipping downloading binaries on CI builds

    > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall
    C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
    > node lib/post_install.js


    > node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/build.js

    Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
    C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext=
    --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
    gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
    gyp info using node@10.1.0 | win32 | x64
    gyp verb command rebuild []
    gyp verb command clean []
    gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    gyp verb command configure []
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
    (C:\Users\SESA499689\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
    (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError
    (C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F
    (C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E
    (C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at
    C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at
    C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at
    C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete
    (fs.js:165:21)',
    gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
    (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
    (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError
    (C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F
    (C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E
    (C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at
    C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at
    C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at
    C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete
    (fs.js:165:21)',
    gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
    gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
    gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
    gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
    gyp ERR! configure error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython
    (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous>
    (C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
    gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
    "C:\\Users\\S\\myapptest\\testapp2\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose"
    "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\User\S\myapptest\testapp2\node_modules\node-sass
    gyp ERR! node -v v10.1.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok
    Build failed with error code: 1
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted
    {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\S\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-15T05_31_39_922Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try npm i rebuild-node-sass

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have python installed. Try installing/reinstalling it first.   [Here is the Download-Link](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

And it is never bad to rebuild node-sass with `npm rebuild node-sass`